# Django problem - cannot get the value from the front - query value is none

Tags: python, django

I've got a problem with an basic searcher app - its about to searching the database for the value that i will be taping in the search bar. I was trying to get the solution from the internet, but there is none or its hard to find something. I was looking for some tut, but none of them works in my app.
Main problem is : ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value. I know that this query is none, but i dont get it why and how.
So, this is my base.html form code:

```
<form type="GET" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search..."/>
    <input type="submit" value='Search' />
</form>
```

views.py:

```
class FilmListView(ListView):
    model = Film
    template_name = 'searcher/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'films'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3

    query = request.GET.get('query')
    queryset_list = Film.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', FilmListView.as_view(), name='search-home'),
    path('films/', SearchedFilmListView.as_view(), name='searched-films'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserFilmListView.as_view(), name='user-films'),
    path('film/<int:pk>/', FilmDetailView.as_view(), name='film-detail'),
    path('film/new/', FilmCreateView.as_view(), name='film-create'),
    path('film/<int:pk>/update/', FilmUpdateView.as_view(), name='film-update'),
    path('film/<int:pk>/delete/', FilmDeleteView.as_view(), name='film-delete'),    
    path('about/', views.about, name='search-about'),
]
```

The other thing in this app is that i have to import request to make it work.

If you got any solution or any tips just help. THX for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the get method on a dictionary will return None, so when someone goes to the page without using the form the query value is None trying changing the following line:

```
query = request.GET.get('query')
```

to

```
query = request.GET.get('query', ‘’)
```

It would be better to change the query in the get_queryset method of the view like so

```
def get_queryset(self):
   query = self.request.GET.get('query')
    if query:
       queryset = Film.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    else:
        queryset = Film.objects.all()
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 2):

That code wouldn't give you that error. It would give you a NameError, because `request` is not defined at class level.

You need to put that into the `get_queryset` method, and also only filter if a value is provided.

```
class FilmListView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('query')
        if query:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=query)
        return qs
```